# How to delete HERE SDK credentials

Tags: here-api, heremaps-android-sdk

I need to invalidate my current HereMaps Android Premium SDK credentials and create new ones. There is currently no way to do this. I'm in Projects > [Project-Name] > HERE SDK for Android (Premium), and there's no option to invalidate/reset.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able able to disable/delete? Can you be able to provide a screenshot of what you see?[image]

Comment: Those are for HERE SDKs Lite and Explore. I'm using Premium. This is what I see:
https://imgur.com/a/2LdPvQH

Comment: Hmm let me reach out to the teams and figure this out for you.